# No funciona alerta en apache cordova

Tags: javascript, botón, apache-cordova, alert

Intento mostrar un mensaje luego de contar unas vocales, me funciona bien, pero cuando lo llevo a apache córdova en Visual Studio 2017, no.

app.js

```
  function mostrarAlerta(mensaje) {

    //alert(mensaje);

    //navigator.notification.alert(mensaje);

    navigator.notification.alert(
        mensaje
    );
}
```

index.html

```
<script src="merges/android/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <title>InaltecApp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Pantalla 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="pantalla2.html">Pantalla 2</a></li>

    </ul>
    <br>
    <h2>Pantalla 1</h2>

    <label for='instrucciones'>Ingresar :</label>
    </p>
    <textarea id='txtEntrada' rows='5' cols='50' style='resize:none;'></textarea>
    </p>
    <button type="button" id="btnContarVocales" name="btnContarVocales">
        <!--onClick="mostrarAlerta();-->
        Contar vocales
    </button> <br><br>
    <label id="respuesta">___</label>


    <br><br>
    <h2>Imagen</h2>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <img src="images/img1.jpg" />
        <img class="top" src="images/img6.jpg" />
    </div>



    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $('#btnContarVocales').on('click', function () {
                /*
                Se obtiene el texto ingresado, se le quitan los espacios en blanco,
                se convierte a minusculas y se encapsula en la variable '_parrafo'.
                */
                var parrafo = ($('#txtEntrada').val()).toLowerCase();
                var vocales = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
                var contadorVocales = 0;
                var contadorNumeros = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < parrafo.length; i++) {
                    if (parrafo[i] == vocales[0] || parrafo[i] == vocales[0] || parrafo[i] == vocales[1] || parrafo[i] == vocales[2] || parrafo[i] == vocales[3] || parrafo[i] == vocales[4]) {
                        contadorVocales += 1;
                    }

                    if (parrafo[i] == '0' || parrafo[i] == '1' || parrafo[i] == '2' || parrafo[i] == '3' || parrafo[i] == '4' || parrafo[i] == '5' || parrafo[i] == '6' || parrafo[i] == '7' || parrafo[i] == '8' || parrafo[i] == '9') {
                        contadorNumeros += 1;
                    }


                }

                var resultado = 'Vocales: ' + contadorVocales + '\nNúmeros: ' + contadorNumeros;
                //alert(resultado);
                /*navigator.notification.alert(
                    resultado
                ); */
                //document.getElementById('respuesta').innerHTML = resultado;
                mostrarAlerta(resultado);
            });





        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

El botón simplemente no hace nada.

index.js

```
function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Controlar la pausa de Cordova y reanudar eventos
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);   
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // TODO: Cordova se ha cargado. Haga aquí las inicializaciones que necesiten Cordova.
        var parentElement = document.getElementById('deviceready');
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        function onDeviceReady() {
            console.log(navigator.notification);
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

En la [Documentación](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/es/3.1.0/cordova/notification/notification.alert.html) de apache cordova muestra que un alert no es como un alert normal. 
Vamos, la sintaxis de la función es distinta.

```
function alertDismissed() {
    // do something
}

navigator.notification.alert(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    alertDismissed,         // callback
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Done'                  // buttonName
);
```

**Ejemplo sacado de la [Documentación](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/es/3.1.0/cordova/notification/notification.alert.html)**

Comment: Intenté eso y nada. @matahombres

Comment: te saca algún error?

Comment: No. Simplemente el botón no hace nada @matahombres

Comment: Mira a ver si en los complementos tienes el plugin ```Notification```